# Can not download the file from server in android web view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to download a file from my school web view app.

When I open my school website in chrome (android) it downloads my marks file, but in my Web view app it does not download. But then my Web view app can download course material inside Web view fine.

I have already implemented the download listener. In debugging i check that clicking on marks button it does not enter in to download block code?

Comment: I reworded your question a bit to make it more readable. But beyond that, you have to provide more input. Please read [mcve] and try to give us the relevant parts of you code. Nobody can tell you what is wrong about your app when you not show us source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should set download listener to you web view just like this:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLengt[h) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

you can learn more about DownloadListener from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/DownloadListener)